# Python сортировка элементов матрицы

Tags: python, матрицы, массивы

Добрый день!

Хотел разобраться с сортировкой элементов матрицы, которые находятся на диагоналях.

B Python я новичок, от чтения документации и своего кода пока что голова идет кругом, поэтому обращаюсь за помощью.

Есть класс matrix, в котором описаны базовые действия с матрицей.
Нужно прикрутить сюда же (желательно) сортировку элементов, расположенных на диагоналях матрицы.

Код класса, который есть на данный момент (версия python 3.3):

```
import random
import operator
import sys
import unittest


class MatrixError(Exception):
    """ An exception class for Matrix """
    pass


class Matrix(object):
    """ A simple Python matrix class with
    basic operations and operator overloading """

    def __init__(self, m, n, init=True):
        if init:
            self.rows = [[0]*n for x in range(m)]
        else:
            self.rows = []
        self.m = m
        self.n = n

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        return self.rows[idx]

    def __setitem__(self, idx, item):
        self.rows[idx] = item

    def __str__(self):
        s='\n'.join([' '.join([str(item) for item in row]) for row in self.rows])
        return s + '\n'

    def __repr__(self):
        s=str(self.rows)
        rank = str(self.getRank())
        rep="Matrix: \"%s\", rank: \"%s\"" % (s,rank)
        return rep

    def reset(self):
        """ Reset the matrix data """
        self.rows = [[] for x in range(self.m)]

    def transpose(self):
        """ Transpose the matrix. Changes the current matrix """

        self.m, self.n = self.n, self.m
        self.rows = [list(item) for item in zip(*self.rows)]

    def getTranspose(self):
        """ Return a transpose of the matrix without
        modifying the matrix itself """

        m, n = self.n, self.m
        mat = Matrix(m, n)
        mat.rows =  [list(item) for item in zip(*self.rows)]

        return mat

    def getRank(self):
        return (self.m, self.n)

    def __eq__(self, mat):
        """ Test equality """

        return (mat.rows == self.rows)

    def __add__(self, mat):
        """ Add a matrix to this matrix and
        return the new matrix. Doesn't modify
        the current matrix """

        if self.getRank() != mat.getRank():
            raise (MatrixError, "Trying to add matrixes of varying rank!")

        ret = Matrix(self.m, self.n)

        for x in range(self.m):
            row = [sum(item) for item in zip(self.rows[x], mat[x])]
            ret[x] = row

        return ret

    def __sub__(self, mat):
        """ Subtract a matrix from this matrix and
        return the new matrix. Doesn't modify
        the current matrix """

        if self.getRank() != mat.getRank():
            raise (MatrixError, "Trying to add matrixes of varying rank!")

        ret = Matrix(self.m, self.n)

        for x in range(self.m):
            row = [item[0]-item[1] for item in zip(self.rows[x], mat[x])]
            ret[x] = row

        return ret

    def __mul__(self, mat):
        """ Multiple a matrix with this matrix and
        return the new matrix. Doesn't modify
        the current matrix """

        matm, matn = mat.getRank()

        if (self.n != matm):
            raise (MatrixError, "Matrices cannot be multipled!")

        mat_t = mat.getTranspose()
        mulmat = Matrix(self.m, matn)

        for x in range(self.m):
            for y in range(mat_t.m):
                mulmat[x][y] = sum([item[0]*item[1] for item in zip(self.rows[x], mat_t[y])])

        return mulmat

    def __iadd__(self, mat):
        """ Add a matrix to this matrix.
        This modifies the current matrix """

        # Calls __add__
        tempmat = self + mat
        self.rows = tempmat.rows[:]
        return self

    def __isub__(self, mat):
        """ Add a matrix to this matrix.
        This modifies the current matrix """

        # Calls __sub__
        tempmat = self - mat
        self.rows = tempmat.rows[:]     
        return self

    def __imul__(self, mat):
        """ Add a matrix to this matrix.
        This modifies the current matrix """

        # Possibly not a proper operation
        # since this changes the current matrix
        # rank as well...

        # Calls __mul__
        tempmat = self * mat
        self.rows = tempmat.rows[:]
        self.m, self.n = tempmat.getRank()
        return self

    def save(self, filename):
        open(filename, 'w').write(str(self))

    @classmethod
    def _makeMatrix(cls, rows):

        m = len(rows)
        n = len(rows[0])
        # Validity check
        if any([len(row) != n for row in rows[1:]]):
            raise (MatrixError, "inconsistent row length")
        mat = Matrix(m,n, init=False)
        mat.rows = rows

        return mat

    @classmethod
    def makeRandom(cls, m, n, low=0, high=10):
        """ Make a random matrix with elements in range (low-high) """

        obj = Matrix(m, n, init=False)
        for x in range(m):
            obj.rows.append([random.randrange(low, high) for i in range(obj.n)])

        return obj

    @classmethod
    def makeZero(cls, m, n):
        """ Make a zero-matrix of rank (mxn) """

        rows = [[0]*n for x in range(m)]
        return cls.fromList(rows)

    @classmethod
    def makeId(cls, m):
        """ Make identity matrix of rank (mxm) """

        rows = [[0]*m for x in range(m)]
        idx = 0

        for row in rows:
            row[idx] = 1
            idx += 1

        return cls.fromList(rows)

    @classmethod
    def readStdin(cls):
        """ Read a matrix from standard input """

        print ('Enter matrix row by row. Type "q" to quit')
        rows = []
        while True:
            line = sys.stdin.readline().strip()
            if line=='q': break

            row = [int(x) for x in line.split()]
            rows.append(row)

        return cls._makeMatrix(rows)

    @classmethod
    def readGrid(cls, fname):
        """ Read a matrix from a file """

        rows = []
        for line in open(fname).readlines():
            row = [int(x) for x in line.split()]
            rows.append(row)

        return cls._makeMatrix(rows)

    @classmethod
    def fromList(cls, listoflists):
        """ Create a matrix by directly passing a list
        of lists """

        # E.g: Matrix.fromList([[1 2 3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]])

        rows = listoflists[:]
        return cls._makeMatrix(rows)


class MatrixTests(unittest.TestCase):
    def testAdd(self):
        m1 = Matrix.fromList([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
        m2 = Matrix.fromList([[7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]])        
        m3 = m1 + m2
        self.assertTrue(m3 == Matrix.fromList([[8, 10, 12], [14,16,18]]))

    def testSub(self):
        m1 = Matrix.fromList([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
        m2 = Matrix.fromList([[7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]])        
        m3 = m2 - m1
        self.assertTrue(m3 == Matrix.fromList([[6, 6, 6], [6, 6, 6]]))

    def testMul(self):
        m1 = Matrix.fromList([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
        m2 = Matrix.fromList([[7, 8], [10, 11], [12, 13]])
        self.assertTrue(m1 * m2 == Matrix.fromList([[63, 69], [150, 165]]))
        self.assertTrue(m2*m1 == Matrix.fromList([[39, 54, 69], [54, 75, 96], [64, 89, 114]]))

    def testTranspose(self):

        m1 = Matrix.makeRandom(25, 30)
        zerom = Matrix.makeZero(25, 30)
        m2 = m1 + zerom

        m1.transpose()
        m1.transpose()
        self.assertTrue(m2 == m1)

        # Also test getTranspose
        m2 = m1.getTranspose()
        r2 = m2.getRank()

        self.assertTrue(r2==(30,25))
        m2.transpose()

        self.assertTrue(m2 == m1)

    def testId(self):

        m1 = Matrix.makeId(10)
        m2 = Matrix.makeRandom(4, 10)
        m3 = m2*m1
        self.assertTrue(m3 == m2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: Вы серьезно думаете, что кто-то будет это читать?

Comment: Может, пока я допиливаю код, кто-нибудь выскажет свое мнение.
Спасибо что заглянули.

Comment: Как сортировка должна выглядеть с т.з. пользователя? Вызвать метод sort у объекта матрицы, который вернет отсортированный список элементов на диагонали?

Comment: Для работы с матрицами лучше используйте NumPy, а не пишите велосипеды.

Comment: fogbit, в точку. 
Пользователь вызывает метод sort и получает отсортированную последовательность элементов.

mikillskegg, я бы с радостью использовал NumPy или SciPy, если бы расчеты эти были нужны лично для меня, или, скажем, на работе для большого количества пользователей.

а так...учебное заведение требует велосипедов.

Comment: Наверное я чего-то сильно не понимаю, но IMHO великовата простыня для сортировки. Тем более, что просто сортировка в питоне наверняка есть.

На Си я бы сделал так. Скопировал за один проход элементы диагонали  в вектор, отсортировал его а потом заменил по месту элементы диагонали.

    typeof(a[0][0]) v[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
      v[i] = a[i][i];
    qsort(v,n,sizeof(*v),cmp);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
      a[i][i] = v[i];

Или идея сортировки элементов диагонали принципиально иная?

Comment: Почему же, примерно так и есть. 
Уже продвигаюсь в сторону нужного результата.
Как буду уверен в работоспособности - выложу сюда.

Answer (score -1):

Вот простой пузырьковый метод сортировки диагонали матрицы.
В класс сами добавите или помочь?

```
from random import randrange as rnd
nc = 10
nr = 10
a = [[rnd(10) for c in range(nc)] for r in range(nr)]
for r in a:
    print(*r)


for k in range(nr-1): 
    for i in range(nc-1):
        if a[i][i] < a[i+1][i+1]:
            a[i][i],a[i+1][i+1] = a[i+1][i+1],a[i][i]


print()
for r in a:
    print(*r)
```

Comment: Довольно бессмысленно обращаться к автору вопроса через 4 года после того как вопрос был задан.

Comment: Есть и другие люди, которые могут найти поиском эту страницу.

Comment: Найти могут, но на ваше обращение в ответе автор вряд ли когда-нибудь ответит.

Comment: А, точно. Значит сам справился.